# Paginação springBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Sou novato com Spring e desenvolvimento web e estou tendo problemas para paginar um select, esse é o método que faz a busca:

```
public static Page getAllPeople(Connection connection, Pageable pageable) {
ArrayList<peopleDto> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();
DSLContext ctx = null;
peopleDto peopleDto;
try {
    ctx = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    Result<Record> result = ctx.select()
            .from(people)
            .orderBy(people.GNUM)
            .offset(pageable.getOffset())
            .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
            .fetch();

    for (Record r : result) {

        peopleDto = new peopleDto();
        peopleDto.setpeopleID(r.getValue(people.GNUM));
        peopleDto.setName(r.get(people.SNAME));
        peopleDto.setRM(r.get(people.SRM));
        peopleDto.setRG(r.get(people.SRG));
        peopleDto.setCertidaoLivro(r.get(people.SCERT));
        peopleDto.setCertidaoDistrito(r.get(people.SCERTD));
        peopleList.add(peopleDto);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e.toString());
} finally {
    if (ctx != null) {
    ctx.close();
    }
}
return new PageImpl(peopleList, pageable, aquiVaiOtotaldaPesquisa?());
```

}

Além da duvida sobre o que é o último parâmetro do PageImpl retornado, tenho também dúvidas de como manipular o retorno desse método, tentei dessa forma mas não funciona como esperado

```
 Page<PeopleDto> page = AlunoManager.getAllPeople(con,PageRequest.of(páginas, tamanho));//?

if(page.hasNext())
getAllPeople(connection, page.nextPageable());
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Por que especificar o número total de elementos?**

Note que podemos criar uma paginação em que cada página possui 10 elementos lá dentro, ou cada página pode conter 20 elementos lá dentro **ou quantos elementos você quiser que tenha** numa única página de acordo com sua necessidade. Como eu vou saber quantas páginas existem no total sem informar o total de elementos existentes? Por isso é necessário informar o total de elementos.

Na implementação de *PageImpl* ao chamar a próxima página com *page.hasNext()*, o seguinte trecho de código é executado:

```
public int getTotalPages() {
    return this.getSize() == 0 ? 1 : (int)Math.ceil((double)this.total / (double)this.getSize());
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.getNumber() + 1 < this.getTotalPages();
}
```

### Como manipular o retorno desse método?

O método *getAllPeople* acaba retornando um *Page*, e a partir tudo está certo para que você vá para a próxima página.

```
public Pageable nextPageable() {
    return this.hasNext() ? this.pageable.next() : Pageable.unpaged();
}
```

Caso não esteja retornando os elementos desejados, veja como estão o seu offset e limit do seu select. Talvez você não esteja paginando corretamente dentro do banco de dados.

**Referências**

How to get List from Page in Spring Data REST

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809580/how-to-get-list-from-page-in-spring-data-rest